# Using custom fonts in PDFKit with Javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I'm trying to use custom ttf fonts in PDFKit with Javascript. Fonts are stored locally. I'm getting a `TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` on `contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);` of [pdfkit.js](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/releases) (line 2429).

I've tried many different custom fonts with no luck. I guess I'm not using the right path format. Standard 14 fonts work fine.

here's my code portion:

```
var doc = new PDFDocument();
var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

        doc.font('fonts/ARLRDBD.ttf')
        .fontSize(15)
        .text(mytext, 100, 66);

        doc.end();
```

Comment: any luck? I'm having similar issues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28168767/1595429